# Adding HTML using DOM?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dom

I'm using Zend_DOM_Query to read HTML elements using DOM.

```
<input type="text" class="a">
<input type="text" class="a">
<input type="text" class="a">
```

I load the html and find the `<input>` and then loop through the results.

```
foreach($inputss as $input){
}
```

What I actually want to do is add additional markup after each `<input>` like another input but of different class name `<input type="text" class="b">`. At the end my full markup will look like this

```
<input type="text" class="a">
<input type="text" class="b">
<input type="text" class="a">
<input type="text" class="b">
<input type="text" class="a">
<input type="text" class="b">
```

I keep seeing examples that use `createElement()` but nothing that seems to add HTML the way I need it added. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is indeed with `createElement`:

```
foreach($inputss as $input){
    $newEl = $input->ownerDocument->createElement('input');
    $newEl->setAttribute('type', 'text');
    $newEl->setAttribute('class', 'b');
    $input->parentElement->insertBefore($newEl, $input->nextSibling);
}
```

Apart from the last line, which is admittedly a little verbose, this seems quite simple to me.

I suppose you *could* do this with `createDocumentFragment` and use `appendXML` to insert a string of HTML, but I don't see that that would be significantly easier or quicker.

NB that the reason this works is that within a `Zend_Dom_Query_Result` object are normal DOM objects, so you can use normal DOM methods on them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this this what you're looking for but this example can be helpfull:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<input type="text" class="a">
<input type="text" class="a">
<input type="text" class="a">
HTML;

$dom    = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath  = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes  = $xpath->query('//input[@class="a"]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $newNode = $node->cloneNode();
    $newNode->setAttribute('class', 'b');
    $node->parentNode->insertBefore($newNode, $node->nextSibling);
}

var_dump(($dom->saveHTML()));
```